# Catching the IllegalArgumentException thrown by PropertyEditors in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a **PropertyEditor** in order to translate ids into *Persons*, with it's setAsText (String text) as follows:

```
public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    try {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(text);
        Person person = peopleService.get(id);
        this.setValue(person);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        // ...
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a number!: " + text);
    }
    catch (PersonNotFoundExcetion ex) {
        // ...
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Impossible to get Person: " + text);
    }
}
```

And my PeopleController has a method as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("/getPerson")
public void ver (@RequestParam Person person, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute (person);
    // ...
}
```

I want to catch the IllegalArgumentException in order to show a friendly message to the user, such as "Sorry, the Person you are looking for isn't here", but I don't know where to do that...

Thanks!

Comment: Well, where do call the method that throws the exception? Also, catching an IllegalArgumentException is usually not the best solution. What's wrong with PersonNotFoundException? Why replace it with the generic and less meaningful IAE?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with PersonNotFoundException, I would throw it if I could, but setAsText() may throw an IAE only, so thats the only way my Controller should be noticed when it can't get the Person...

Comment: I'll echo Martinho and say that it is generally bad form to throw a less specific exception in the process of catching a more specific exception. Obviously we aren't looking at very much of your program, but if you've chosen to handle exceptions in your setAsText method, then why not put handling code in there? You're using Spring, so it isn't like injecting a logger or other notification piece would be all that difficult.

Comment: with "may throw an IAE only" you mean, you're fighting checked exceptions and you can't change the signature of setAsText? Can you make PersonNotFound not checked? Can you throw a non-checked variant of PersonNotFound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General exception handling can be done in this way:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public String handleAllExceptions(Exception e) {
  return "redirect:/error.html"; /* use the correct view name */
}
```

More specfic you could use BindingResult

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/datedata", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(
    @ModelAttribute("datedata") final DateData datedata,
    final BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "datedata/create";
    } else {
        ...
        return "myView";
    }
 }
```

But I guess this works only for "Forms" (ModelAttribute)

*In my humble opinion it is not a good idea to let Spring handle validaten of user input by property editors. I would strongly recommend to use the Form way: Build a command object with a STRING field an use a validator on it.*

Comment: It might be a tad difficult to find the correct view with something as generic (and user-unfriendly) as an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: "generic" was not a requirement

Answer (score 1):

The exception ought to be caught in the Controller.  It should never leak out to the view and end user.

If this is a web app, I'd recommend using the validation and binding API rather than PropertyEditor.  That will allow you to return Errors that you can use to tell the UI what needs to be corrected.

Your exception handling needs work.  I would not recommend catching an exception and doing nothing other than wrapping it and re-throwing.  That's not handling anything or adding new information.  It's actually less information as coded.

Comment: You are right duffymo, I did'n include the handling code in order to be brief, thats why the "// ..." is there, btw I will consider using the validation and binding API, thanks